# Find if there is a correlation between two paired data points

Tags: correlation, anova, cohens-kappa

I have two lists of data with each 10 values from 10 participants.

Let’s say the first list contains IQ’s of the 10 participants.

And the second list contains how many words each 10 participants can type per minute.

How can I tell if there is a relationship between the data points and it isn’t coincidental?

Kappa comes to mind and maybe the paired T rest??

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cohen's kappa and t-tests address different questions from the one you are interested in. A couple of simple alternatives you could try are (1) calculating a correlation coefficient, or (2) using a regression to quantify the relationship between the two variables.

Answer (score 2):

Call me crazy, but you might want to start by **plotting your data**.  I recommend you start with a scatterplot and compute [Pearson's sample correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient).  There are some formal tests you can use to check if the true correlation is zero; bear in mind that most of these require assumptions about the distributional form of the data, though you are unlikely to falsify these assumptions with so little data.